# Django - links are incorrectly resolved in menu

Tags: django, django-templates, django-urls

I am developing locally Django page and have some issues with highlighted menus.

- when hover over "moje projekty" I see below link

`127.0.0.1:8080/portfolio/`, I click  and page opens

- when now I hover hover 2nd time, it is showing:

`127.0.0.1:8080/portfolio/portfolio/`, I click  and page opens

- when now I hover hover 3rd time,it is showing:

`127.0.0.1:8080/portfolio/portfolio/portfolio/`, I click and error is:

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8080/portfolio/portfolio/portfolio/
Using the URLconf defined in my_site.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

admin/
[name='home']
about_me/ [name='aboutme']
portfolio/ [name='portfolio']
posts/<slug:the_slug>/ [name='post_detail']
summernote/
^media/(?P<path>.*)$
portfolio/ [name='home']
portfolio/ about_me/ [name='aboutme']
portfolio/ portfolio/ [name='portfolio']
portfolio/ posts/<slug:the_slug>/ [name='post_detail']
portfolio/ summernote/
portfolio/ ^media/(?P<path>.*)$
about_me/
The current path, portfolio/portfolio/portfolio/, didn’t match any of these.
```

base.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <title>Moja strona</title>
         <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,700" rel="stylesheet">
        <meta name="google" content="notranslate" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm"
            crossorigin="anonymous" />
    </head>

    <body>
        <style>
            body {
            font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
            font-size: 17px;
            background-color: #fdfdfd;
        }
        .shadow {
            box-shadow: 0 4px 2px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
        }
        .btn-danger {
            color: #fff;
            background-color: #f00000;
            border-color: #dc281e;
        }
        .masthead {
            background: #3398E1;
            height: auto;
            padding-bottom: 15px;
            box-shadow: 0 16px 48px #E3E7EB;
            padding-top: 10px;
        }
        img {
            width: 00%;
            height: auto;
            object-fit: contain; 
    </style>
        {% load static %}
               <center> <img src="{% static 'blog/moj.png' %}" alt="My image"> </center>

        <!-- Navigation -->
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-light bg-light shadow" id="mainNav">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                
                
                <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive"
                    aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                        <li class="nav-item text-black">
                            <a class="nav-link text-black font-weight-bold" href="/">Blog</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item text-black">
                            <a class="nav-link text-black font-weight-bold" href="portfolio/">Moje projekty</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item text-black">
                            <a class="nav-link text-black font-weight-bold" href="about_me">Kontakt</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
        {% block content %}
        <!-- Content Goes here -->
        {% endblock content %}
        <!-- Footer -->

    </body>
</html>
```

urls.py project:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('blog.urls')),
     path('portfolio/', include('blog.urls')),
     path('about_me/', include('blog.urls')),
    ]
```

urls.py app:

```
from . import views
from django.urls import path
from django.conf.urls import include

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.PostList.as_view(), name='home'),
    path('about_me/', views.Aboutme.as_view(), name='aboutme'),
    path('portfolio/', views.Portfolio.as_view(), name='portfolio'),
   
    path('posts/<slug:the_slug>/', views.PostDetail.as_view(), name='post_detail'),
    path('summernote/', include('django_summernote.urls')),


    ]
# to jest dla wysiwyg
  # add condition in django urls file

from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root = settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Questions:

- why link is changing 2nd time when I click?
- why I am getting this error after 3rd click?

Comment: It appends to current url because `href="portfolio/"` is a relative url.

Answer (score 1):

Hey :) the paths /portfolio/ and /portfolio/portfolio/ are correct, but when you use htm href='portfolio/' without forward slash they are not absolute. html just add it to existing one. So if u in example.com/portfolio/ and click this href you adds another 'portfolio/'.

just use in href :

```
 <a class="nav-link text-black font-weight-bold" href="{% url 'blog:portfolio' %}">
```

PS. in urls.py for project you don't need two paths to the same app